# XPath expression from a website to extract price

Tags: wordpress, xpath

I try to extract the xpath for my content egg plugin on wordpress, but on those 2 websites i can't really find the right xpath. If is someone here to help me i be gratefull.

On the first one, for example: https://www.pcgarage.ro/sisteme-pc-garage/pc-garage/gaming-ares-iv/

I tried:

```
//span[contains(text(),'26.999,99 RON')]
.//*[@*itemprop='price']
```

And

```
//span[@class='price_num']
```

On the second one: https://www.emag.ro/aparat-de-aer-conditionat-heinner-crystal-9000-btu-clasa-a-functie-incalzire-filtru-cu-densitate-ridicata-follow-me-functie-turbo-r32-alb-hac-cr09whn/pd/DGW0DJBBM/?ref=hp_prod-widget_flash_deals_1_1&provider=site

`//span[@class='product-new-price']` (this works but they give me and the `<sup>` with 99 (i don't need this), if is a way to exclude sup, would be great)

Answer (score 0):

The XPath to get the price on the first page is

```
//td[@class='pip_text']//b
```

For the second site you can use this:

```
//div[@class='product-highlights-wrapper']//p[@class='product-new-price']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but when i introduce in content egg doesn't works.

Comment: Content egg is a plugin in wordpress what the take the price from a website and based on a cron job or a page view, he update de price of the product. I attach you a link, maybe help you. https://ce-docs.keywordrush.com/modules/affiliate/offermodule